# USB-charger installed nearby Harley-Davidson Engine

Tags: harley-davidson

I recently asked my mechanic whether it's a good idea to install an USB-charger on the left (hot-running) engine-side of a Harley-Davidson Street Bob 2016 (103 ci)?

There are USB-chargers that can be installed on the horn:

[image]

but is this really a good idea when it comes to loading a smartphone during a drive? Even if this charger (in the picture) is suitable, have there ever been problems with USB-smartphones-cables themselves, in terms of loading a smartphone while the engine is running?

The reason for this question is that I do not want to install a charger on the handlebar or somewhere above the tank, simply because it looks ugly.

Furthermore the USB-smartphone-cable should be under the tank as well, because I'm afraid that the cable can become loose during a drive, caused by the wind and shaking engine.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How hot do you think it will be there? What about under the seat for example... Have you considered some of the waterproof usb ports available...

Comment: Yes, I've considered this, but the reason why I little moved away from this idea is because the usb-smartphone-cable. I want to see my smartphone on the handlebars of course, but when a charger is installed under the seat the usb-cable has to lie upon the tank to reach the charger. How can I make sure that the cable is not shaked off the tank? This engine shakes a lot and I'm afraid that the cable can become loose.

Comment: When charger is installed on the horn, then the usb-cable does not have to be laid on the tank, but  it can be under the tank to reach the charger. Furthermore, please do not take me wrong, I do not want to see my usb-cable running upon the tank.

Comment: Start at the end and work backwards. Decide where you want the phone mounted. Tell the mechanic what you want the end result to look like and let him figure it out. They can decide on best type,  location and routing of cables and can probably hide the charger